# How to send emai using SMTP server in iphone sdk without using Composer Window?

Tags: iphone, email, ios4

Here In My app, There is a case where User registering a form
He will give his mail id in one textfield. After Complete the form I need to send a mail to User for conformation of his registering.

Any one can help me please.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its the right way to send email from the phone to the user's email id. You need to process the form at a remote server and it should send the confirmation email which most of the phone apps with user registration do. If you are going to save the user data locally, there will be several problems and the top problem would be rejection of the app from apple.

Comment: Ok actually how can i send email to the user right now. After he filling the form i just check his details and send him for confirmation mail. Ok can you send the source code for most of the apps fallow as early as possible Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

actually its pretty simple, you just have to connect to mail server and send commands

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Hi thanks ,But i didnt get through what You have give site. There is stuff about SMTP  i didnt get any idea about iphone sdk